# How to block access to a specific IP address from docker swarm services

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-networking

I deployed my service with docker swarm in the Digital Ocean VPC.

I want to block access from the service to http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1.json which is the metadata API for security reasons. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to block the IP: `169.254.169.254`

**1. Block the IP in the host machine**

```
# to block:
$ route add -host 169.254.169.254 reject

# to show the current routes:
$ route
```

**2. Block the IP for docker container only in the docker filter chain with `iptables`**

```
# to block
$ iptables -I DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -d 169.254.169.254 -j DROP

# to show the current tables:
$ iptables -vL
```

Answer (score 1):

You should block it on your host-machine, Docker use host-machine network configuration, so if your host-machine use iptables, you could use [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-6-how-to-block-outgoing-access-to-selectedspecific-ip-address.html) to block access.

Also you could block egress traffic from Docker using same iptables, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137191/5625691).

Comment: I don't want to block on the host-machine. Because some background agents use that APIs for stats.

Comment: @QuyTang I updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Hi Alex,
Thanks for your help!
After reading some documents about iptables and your included references. I figure out the answer as below - https://serverfault.com/a/1107080/977687

Comment: The bounty was awarded. Thanks for helping to figure out the answer Alex!